# ¿Cómo evitar que salga signo de interrogación en HTML al usar el lenguaje árabe?

Tags: html, css

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<title>Un document multilingue</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Hola</p>
<p>Canción</p>
<p lang="ar" dir="rtl">مرحبا</p>
</body>
</html>
```

He intentando:

- Usar `charset UTF-8` y nada; sigue saliendo "?"
- Coloqué todo el código en un campo de texto (mysql) y se muestra bien.
- Creo que es alguna configuración en el servidor (xampp), pero no sé, al subirlo a un servidor web y sale con el mismo error.
- También intenté con PHP con este código, pero sigue el mismo error:

---

```
$x='<p lang="ar" dir="rtl">مرحبا</p>';
    echo $x; idem,
```

Ests es el [enlace de la página](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZpmG.png) en donde se puede ver el error *(es decir, no se muestran los caracteres en árabe)*.

---

http://tukeque.com/seguro/parrafo.htm

Ese enlace nuestra el error.

También en localhost:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Hola decoro, agrega una explicación de tu pregunta dentro del cuerpo de la misma, esto ayudará a que más personas de la comunidad puedan entender y ayudarte en tu pregunta, revisar [ask].

Comment: proba poniendo un archivo  `.htaccess` con `AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .php .txt .js` puede que apache levante con el charset del sistema operativo y este no sea utf-8

Comment: Descargando esa página directamente con un cliente como wget o curl en lugar de usar un navegador, y examinando el HTML que llega, se ve que el propio html ya viene con interrogantes. Incluso mirándolo con un editor hexadecimal, se ven los interrogantes ascii (código `3f`) y no ningún carácter Unicode. Así que el error lo tienes ya en el editor que uses que te lo guarda así (o al recuperarlo de una base de datos, pues no sabemos en realidad de dónde sacas ese texto).

Comment: @decoro Estoy completamente seguro que el problema es del editor. [El idioma se muestra bien](https://codepen.io/IniDesing/pen/dgKGbe) y si son datos de la base de datos entonces el problema puede venir también de ahí.

Comment: Puedes probar con el UTF-7?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿por qué usas el doctype de HTML 4.01 en lugar del de HTML 5?

Answer (score 1):

He reemplazado la etiqueta `<meta>` con `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` y puedo ver los caracteres en árabe.

Este es el resultado - el único cambio que hice fue la etiqueta `<meta>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <title>Un document multilingue</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hola</p>
  <p>Canción</p>
  <p lang="ar" dir="rtl">مرحبا</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, es que lo copio tal cual y cuando lo ejecuto en mi computador sigue saliendo ??????. No entiendo porqué.

Answer (score -1):

Revisa tu editor de texto como esta guardando el documento, especificamente la codificación que estas usando para guardar el archivo deberia ser tambien UTF8 lo mas problable ese sea tu problema y lo mas seguro en windows que debe estar guardando como ISO-Latin1